# REACT ERROR WHILE IMPORTING THE REACT MODULES

Tags: reactjs

> Attempted import error: 'AlertContainer' is not exported from 'react-alert'.

```
import AlertContainer from 'react-alert'
```

I am getting this import error by running the project

Answer (score 0):

`react-alert` has only named imports:

```
import { transitions, positions, Provider as AlertProvider } from 'react-alert'
```